# UWP CalendarDatePicker issue when setting MinDate and MaxDate - Windows 10 - 1903+

Tags: uwp

I've a CalendarDatePicker named "cdp"
I set MinDate and MaxDate to DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(2) and DateTime.MaxValue.AddYears(-2)

```
cdp.MinDate = DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(2);
cdp.MaxDate = DateTime.MaxValue.AddYears(-2);
```

When showing CalendarView I'm getting this issue

[CalendarDatePickerIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7udMe.png)

I'm getting this issue on Windows10 Version 1903 - 1909 not on Windows 10 Version 1803 neither Windows 10 Version 1703 !
CalendarDatePicker works fine with default MinValue and default MaxValue.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of DateTime.MinValue is 1/1/0001 and the value of DateTime.MaxValue is 12/31/9999. While the default value of cdp.MinDate is 1/1/1902 and the default value of cdp.MaxDate is 12/31/2120. The result of `DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(2)`  still exceeds the range of cdp.MinDate. It is better if you could use `cdp.MinDate.AddYears(2)` to replace `DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(2)`. And, I can not reproduce the issue with the code by you, could you please provide us with a [mcve] by using OneDrive or GitHub?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT  :Thanks for your help. Example can be downloaded here : [Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AG3KZylMX22Htm4&cid=6F4E957DF40C8BE4&id=6F4E957DF40C8BE4%21910&parId=root&action=locate)  Code is developped with vs2017, example is in MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The **Target version** property is Windows 10, version 1809 in your sample project. You need to change the **Target version** property to a higher version than version 1809(such as version 1903 or version 2004) to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, 
  1."Windows 10, version 1809(10.0; Build 17763)" is the "higher" target version provided in my VS2017 environnement.
  2. In fact, I need lower Target Version cause my product is developped under VS2015 and used under Windows10 1703 and Windows10 1903
:-(

Comment: If you need your project to be built in Windows 10, version 1809, why not use code `cdp.MinDate = cdp.MinDate.AddYears(2);` to replace code `cdp.MinDate = DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(2);` . If you need more operation conversion between DateTime and DateTimeOffset, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset).

Comment: In real life, Min and Max values to be assigned to cdp.MinDate and to cdp.MaxDate are determinated in a specific class. Under spoecifics circonstances values are DateTime.MinDate.AddYears(2) and DateTime.MaxDate.AddYears(-2).

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. You could go to the Feedback Hub and submit a feedback about the issue.